# Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

Tags: jframe

```
jb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

           @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        .access$0(()1.this).CSV_File1 = 1.this.AutoCSV.this.showSaveFileDialog();
                        .access$0(()1.this).jtf1.setText(.access$0(()1.this).CSV_File1);
                    }
                });
            }

        });
```

The error i'm getting are as follows.

Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete 
     MethodBody
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete 
     ClassBody
    - implements java.lang.Runnable.run

please somebody help me